# how to add column after dividing working hours in SQL

Tags: sql

My bigquery table has a start time and an finish time. I want to add number 1 to the start time, but I want to do it as much as the end time. How can I do that?
this is my bigquery table and I want to show this table to below table.

For example

[MY bigquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bc211.png)

Results

----> [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N64FP.png)

Comment: I've removed the tag spam here. Please tag correctly.

Comment: Please take the time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Please do not post code, tables, or text as screenshots. If you could edit the question back to how it was formatted previously. No one wants to click on links and transcribe pictures to reproduce in their environment when helping.

Comment: i do recommend to use a fiddle ie. http://sqlfiddle.com/ hope it helps you.